# LINQ query bool value to pass in a different Int

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

Afternoon,
I am passing in a bool value from a text box, and i need to check to see if its true or false then add the correct codetype (int) for it to search by.

for example

```
if (hasASIN == true)
{
    int show = 5;
}
else {
    int show = 1, 2, 3, 4 (these are the other code types)
}
```

i then would need to add a where clause to my LINQ statement.

```
where a.codeType == show (need to have this maybe in a || (or) bit so i can use the other code types)
```

below is my existing LINQ Code

```
 var query = from a in dc.aboProducts
             join t in dc.tweProducts on a.sku equals t.sku

             where (string.IsNullOrEmpty(productSku) || productSku == t.sku)
             where (string.IsNullOrEmpty(productAsin) || productAsin == a.asin)
             where (string.IsNullOrEmpty(productName) || t.title.Contains(productName))
             where (string.IsNullOrEmpty(productBrand) || t.brand.Contains(productBrand))
             where a.amzPrice >= priceFrom && a.amzPrice <= (priceTo)
             where a.amzLive == isLive 

             select new GetProducts
             {
                productid = Convert.ToInt32(t.id),
                sku = t.sku,
                title = t.title,
                tweprice = Convert.ToString(t.twePrice),
                stock = Convert.ToInt32(t.stock),
                asin = a.asin,
                amzprice = Convert.ToString(a.amzPrice),
                amzlive = Convert.ToBoolean(a.amzLive),
                lastupdated = Convert.ToDateTime(t.lastUpdated)
             };
  return query.ToList();
```

I hope i have explained this ok, if not feel free to ask away :) Thanks in advance.

Comment: how would i go about doing it so i can check for either codetype 5, or codetype 1,2,3 and 4 ? :) sorry forgot that! My excuse its Friday lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much search i found the answer which worked a treat...

```
where (hasASIN == true && a.codeType == 5) || (a.codeType == 1 || a.codeType == 2 || a.codeType == 3 || a.codeType ==4)
```

Comment: You don't want the products with `codeType` of 1 through 4 when `hasAsin` is true, correct?  If so, then your code should be:
 `where (hasASIN == true && a.codeType == 5) || (hasASIN == false && (a.codeType == 1 || a.codeType == 2 || a.codeType == 3 || a.codeType == 4))`

Answer (score 4):

I would change `int show` to `IEnumerable<int> show`.  Then you can make your if statement

```
IEnumerable<int> show;

if (hasASIN == true)
{
     show = new[] {5};
}
else 
{
     show = new[] {1, 2, 3, 4};
}

var query = ....
```

In your query, you can then have `where show.Contains(a.codeType)`

Comment: I am getting the following error... The name 'show' does not exist in the current context? this is in the where clause.

Comment: Can you post a complete example?

Comment: My guess, based on your original question is that you are declaring `show` inside the `if` or `else` statement.  When you reach the end of this statement, `show` goes out of scope.  You must declare `show` before the `if` so that it remains in scope.

Comment: yeah thats what i did, am getting a couple of errors... `Error 3 Instance argument: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<int>' to 'System.Linq.ParallelQuery<int?>'` and `Error 3 Instance argument: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<int>' to 'System.Linq.ParallelQuery<int?>'`